# How to seek advice/collaboration from other profs in the dept

Tags: etiquette, collaboration

I am a postdoc who changed the topic quite drastically entering the postdoc phase.
The big issue is that my advisor does not provide any guidance or advice at all regarding my project.
It has been quite difficult for me to come up with a good research topic in a whole new field on my own and I would like to seek advice from another professor.

Would this be rather unusual? Thinking from other professor's perspective, I don't think they will be too willing to spend time on someone else's postdoc. 
Ideally, I want a situation where I can continue to discuss my work with another prof and get advice from regularly, but I am also trying to look a for a topic that will allow collaboration with other groups.

I can put in the time and our lab has good funding so I feel like I just need a little bit of insight from more experienced resear.

I would appreciate any advice! Thank you.

Comment: Does your advisor provide your funding? Was the current project his/hers?

Comment: He provides funding but that's pretty much it. To give an example, if we hypothesize that this funding is for cancer research, he is happy as long as I do something cancer and that's about it. The difficulty is that cancer is an extremely broad term and every member in the group does something vastly diff from me (e.g. plant biology).

Comment: Funding is good though and he is supportive of new ideas

Comment: If he is funding you, don't you sort of have to figure out with him something that you can work on together?

Comment: Can you get a collaboration mentor? Someone that you know have great collaboration networks or work well with others that can help guide and provide hints?

Comment: You are a post doc now. You can and should network with other researchers like an independent researcher that you are... For most post docs, most of their time is spent trying to land another job and role. It is quite well expected in most fields that networking and collaboration is expected for ongoing jobs and survival.